# How do I read a scanning electron microscopy (SEM) image and an element of the photo

Tags: microscopy

I'm trying to figure out the information I can take of this image. What I did found out is the following information :

The increase is 600 times.
The voltage is 30.1 kilowatts.
The relief corresponds to 0.1mm or 0.01cm.

**Now, I need to choose an element of the photo and somehow measure with my own 1 or 2 cm, and then transform them in their actual sizes.**

Can you help me with some guidance, please ? Thank you !

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The voltage is 30.1 kV (kiloVolts), not kiloWatts.